# Best chart type for giving smallest value greater importance

Tags: charts, status

I'm building a dashboard, and the client wants some charts to monitor severity of a number of issues. If urgent status requires immediate action, it needs to be instantly noticeable. If I am using a pie chart for example, if only 5 out of 2000 issues are urgent, then it'll be lost in the chart... I'm inclined to ditching the chart idea and just having coloured labels of each status type, with their status name & count, so it is immediately obvious. But it occurred to me there must be a chart type out there that answers this type of query. So imagine there are four statuses with various counts: Low (1500), Medium(400), High (95), Urgent(5). Any ideas? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as you have written there, why put a chart in when text says it much more clearly.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8rhgZ.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Yup. Thanks for confirmation of what I was thinking! :)